# Compress file - Sharing violation on path

Tags: c#, android

I currentlywork on an android application, and I have to develop a function to compress files into directory.

To get all the files, I use the DirectoryInfo() and FileInfo() class and then the ZipArchive() and ZipArchiveEntry() class to create my .zip file.

The problem I have is when I open the file to compress with a FileStream to copy data into my ZipArchive entry. I got a sharing violation on path error when I use the OpenRead() function.

I already check the permissions in my Manifest and try several methods like ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory but I still have the same problem.

Thank you by advance for your help.

Here is my code :

```
public void Compress(DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        string identifiantSC = currentSceneSelected.Id_Scene;
        string typeSceneSelected = currentSceneSelected.type_Scene;

        if (!Directory.Exists (Path.Combine (pathProject, "Archive"))) {
            Directory.CreateDirectory (Path.Combine (pathProject, "Archive"));
        }

        string pathSceneDir = Path.Combine (pathProject, typeSceneSelected + "_" + identifiantSC);
        string pathZipDir = Path.Combine (pathProject, "Archive");

        foreach (var fileToCompress in directory.GetFiles ()) {

            if (!File.Exists (Path.Combine (pathZipDir, typeSceneSelected + "_" + identifiantSC + ".zip"))) {
                try {
                    var fileZip = new FileStream (Path.Combine (pathZipDir, typeSceneSelected + "_" + identifiantSC + ".zip"), FileMode.Create);

                    archive = new ZipArchive (fileZip, ZipArchiveMode.Create);

                    ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry (fileToCompress.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                    FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead();
                    originalFileStream.CopyTo (readmeEntry.Open ());

                } catch (FileLoadException e){
                    Console.WriteLine ("FILE LOAD EXCEPTION : " + e);
                } catch (AccessViolationException e){
                    Console.WriteLine ("ACCESS VIOLATION EXCEPTION : " + e);
                } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e){
                    Console.WriteLine ("ACCESS EXCEPTION : " + e);
                }
            } 
            else {
                using (var fileZip = new FileStream (Path.Combine (pathZipDir, typeSceneSelected + "_" + identifiantSC + ".zip"), FileMode.Open)) {

                    using (archive = new ZipArchive (fileZip, ZipArchiveMode.Update)) {

                        ZipArchiveEntry readmeEntry = archive.CreateEntry (fileToCompress.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);

                        FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead ();
                        originalFileStream.CopyTo (readmeEntry.Open ());
                        originalFileStream.Close ();
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
```